# Sticky footer James Dean - doesnt work as intended

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

i have a problem with sticky footer. I tried to use James Dean solution, using

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
margin: 0 0 125px;
padding: 0px;
}

footer {
background-color: orange;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesnt work as intended - text is also under footer.

Div id="rightinfo" have to be on side, because there will be background image.

Please, does anybody have idea why James Dean doesnt work? Thank you for your answers.

My atemp: https://jsfiddle.net/4po3n6pL/1/

Comment: give proper details what you are trying to do ? give your html code with it

Comment: full code is at jsfiddle